# Is there a generic way to show FPS on NVidia cards?

Tags: graphics-card

Is there a generic command for NVidia cards to show the current framerate while in a game?

More specifically, I'd like to use it on a GeForce 9400 GT in Assassin's Creed Brotherhood, but it would be cool if there was a generic option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no built in generic command to show FPS for Nvidia cards.

Your best bet would be to either use a tool such as [Fraps](http://www.fraps.com/), or enter a console command in the specific game that will display your FPS. the latter option will consume less resources but isn't available in all games.